# MySQL Update Not Working With If Statement

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, json

I'm using AJAX and JSON to update my database, but the values in the database aren't updating.

I know the correct values are getting sent, and also that the correct values are getting returned, but my MySQL update isn't doing anything. It's inside an `if` statement.

**PHP**

```
$youruname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['youruname']);
$selectedplayer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['selectedplayer']);

$flag = "";
$itStatus = "";

$checkit = mysql_query("SELECT it FROM login WHERE uname='$selectedplayer'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($checkit))
{
    $itStatus = $row['it'];
}

if($itStatus === "not it")
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE login SET it='not it' WHERE uname = '$youruname'");
    mysql_query("UPDATE login SET it='it' WHERE uname = '$selectedplayer'");

    $flag = "success";
}
else if($itStatus === "it")
{
    $flag = "nope";
}
else
{
    $flag = "error";
}


echo json_encode(array("message" => $flag, "tagged" => $selectedplayer));
```

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` to catch any errors

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` family of functions - they are deprecated.  Use `mysqli_` or, even better, PDO.

Comment: I've looked all around for how to use PDO, but haven't found any resourced. If you have a link to an explaination about how to use it and where to learn to use it, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just updated code to use `mysqli_` Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: The edit to your question is not valid. Please post it as a comment.

Comment: My new question about the same topic but asking different question and code is very different -- CLICK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887021/mysql-select-not-selecting-anything?lq=1 TO GO TO NEW QUESTION

Answer (score 1):

This may not be part of your question but instead of executing two update statement, you can make it into one,

```
UPDATE login SET it='not it' WHERE uname = '$youruname'
UPDATE login SET it='it' WHERE uname = '$selectedplayer'
```

into

```
UPDATE login 
SET it = CASE WHEN uname = '$youruname' THEN 'not it' ELSE 'it' END
WHERE uname IN ('$youruname', '$selectedplayer')
```

Comment: Good to know, but didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @copilot0910 I already told you the answer not part of the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out.

I was making the call to the DB trying to select a value that didn't exist.

Basically, I was searching for the wrong value.

My code is correct.

And to everyone who offered help, thank you.